# Is there a way to split a string with delimeter without using Regexp

Tags: oracle

I am trying to split a string usin Regexp.

String is comma separated.

Regexp is working but when I am trying to export in CSV it is showing me special characters.

That's why I want to split string without Regex
p.
I used this Code

```sql
select regexp_substr (
         str,
         '[^,]+',
         1,
         level
       ) value
from   rws
connect by level <= 
    length ( str ) - length ( replace ( str, ',' ) ) + 1;
```

Comment: please show the sample data and what is coming out.